# Anaconda Navigator is not showing up

Tags: windows-7, python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I downloaded Anaconda with no problems, but the navigator is absolutely no where to be found.

I'm trying to run Jupyter Notebook and require the navigator to do that, but no matter what folder I look in, the navigator just doesn't exist.

I looked up some answers already and had some people say all you had to do was run the Anaconda Prompt application and type in `anaconda-navigator` to open it up, but I tried that and still got an error message saying the command was invalid. Saw another "answer" say you could open a terminal by pressing `CTRL+ALT+T` and then type the aforementioned command, but the button combination doesn't give me any results.

I'm on Windows 7 by the way and already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda, but still haven't had any luck in finding the missing navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the exact same issue on Windows 10. What helped me was uninstalling Anaconda completely including and installing Anaconda3 5.1.0.

You can find it [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator
```

Might work in your case

Answer (score -1):

Dry version to satisfy the stackoverflow bot here.
For a detailed commentary on how I resolved this issue following Rohit's posting, check out:
[Anaconda Navigator – Windows](https://patrick642.wordpress.com/2022/03/31/anaconda-navigator-windows-installation-issues/) – Installation Issues & Possible Resolution For Ya
This is the BEST answer - props to Rohit.

Anaconda Navigator

Had it on my older Alienware but it is NOT installing properly on my newer HP zBook to give me the Navigator gui.
Most common resolution noted - uninstall Anaconda and re-install it.
Many have tried that (without success) - multiple times and attempting to cleanse the Registry (Windows 10) of all Anaconda references.
Restart and/or reboot after doing so.
Result - no success.

The comment noted by @Rohit to go [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) and pull down the latest file:

```
 === Anaconda3-5.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe     632.5M  2018-11-19 13:38:59 ---
```

After installing, it asks for VS Code installation (if you're like me, you already have it - skip this).

Installed it.  SUCCESS....!!!  Anaconda Prompt // Anaconda Navigator // Spyder // Jupyter Notebook - they ALL appear in the Start area now.

If no success for you, just go with Python3.9 (or 3.10), pip3 and Jupyter Notebook and say scrap Anaconda....

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1117132)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).